# How to remove part of item and replace list elements in loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

What am I doing wrong and these two loops are not working?
links is a list.

```
links = ['newarklongtermparking.com',
 'www.airportparkingreservations.com',
 'airparkparking.com',
 'jfklongtermparking.com',
 'book2park.com',
 'globalairportparking.com',
 'neworleansparking.com',
 'parkwayparking.com',
 'www.airportparkinginc.com',
 'airportparkfly.com',
 'unitedairportparking.com',
 'www.way.com',
 'cheapairportparking.org',
 'wallypark.com',
 'parkbytheports.com',
 'www.cheapparkfly.com']
```

## removing www.

```
for a in links:
    if (a[0] == a[1] == a[2] == 'w'):
        a = a[4:]
```

## adding right form of links

```
for a in links:
    a = 'https://www.' + a
```

Comment: Your question does not give much info as is. Give a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Assigning back to `a` in the first loop won't alter the list references.

Comment: Also, `a.startswith('www')` is a better method of testing if a string starts with specific characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are doing is modifying the loop variable. This does not affect the list at all. If you want to modify the elements in place, I recommend using `enumerate`, and then accessing the list items though their indices:

```
for i, a in enumerate(links):
    prefix = 'https://' if a.startswith('www') else 'https://www.'
    links[i] = prefix + a
```

After processing, this is what `links` has:

```
https://www.newarklongtermparking.com
https://www.airportparkingreservations.com
https://www.airparkparking.com
https://www.jfklongtermparking.com
https://www.book2park.com
https://www.globalairportparking.com
https://www.neworleansparking.com
https://www.parkwayparking.com
https://www.airportparkinginc.com
https://www.airportparkfly.com
https://www.unitedairportparking.com
https://www.way.com
https://www.cheapairportparking.org
https://www.wallypark.com
https://www.parkbytheports.com
https://www.cheapparkfly.com
```

Comment: Think you need: `else links[i] = 'https://www.' + a` since he wants to use all the links in the list, just that some start with 'www.' and others do not

Comment: @nanojohn Well spotted. Thanks.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i would, but it says reputation is too low